# Remove deleted Git repository links from Stack Overflow Developer Story

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

How do I remove deleted Git repository links from my stackoverflow.com developer story?

When viewing my developer-story on stackoverflow.com, it lists Git repositories which I have deleted.

Can I remove those?

Should they update automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hover over the gear icon, and select "Delete".  This will give you a confirmation page to verify if you *actually* want to remove it from your story.

[image]

To my knowledge, Stack Overflow doesn't poll GitHub to check if the repo is live.  I'd imagine that if you want to show it off, you'd be the one verifying that it was still up and in a presentable state.